# In TypeScript, match the callback function more strictly

Tags: typescript, callback

I have function 'a':

```js
function a(f: (k: number) => void) {

}
```

Now i call it like this:

```js
a(function () {
    return 1
})
```

The parameters and return value of the callback function I entered do not match the definition,
But I noticed that the compiler did not notify errors or warnings.

The compiler will give an error only when I declare the wrong type of parameter:

```js
a(function (k: string) {
    return 1
})
// The compiler will notify errors
```

When the number of parameters of the callback function I input does not match, I also hope that the compiler specifies the error.

what should I do?

Thank you

Comment: See [Why are functions with fewer parameters assignable to functions that take more parameters?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters)